# How to clear the selection in the selection service Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

How do I clear the selection in my Eclipse RCP application?

Basically I would like to clear it on escape key down:

```
Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        if (event.character == SWT.ESC) {
            // if this is escape key, clear selection in the application
        }
    }
});
```

I thought I would be able to do something like PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().clearSelection()/setSelection(IStructuredSelection.EMPTY), but no go.

Comment: What does 'no go' mean exactly? I was able to clear the selection with `activePart.getSite().getSelectionProvider().setSelection( StructuredSelection.EMPTY )` if the selection provider was a tree or table viewer. What kind of selection providers do you need to deal with?

Comment: It means that there were no such methods in the selection service itself. I am working on using the suggestion from @greg-449 and it is almost working, but one of my custom ISelectionProviders seems to be bugging, I'll post an update or a new question when I have had another shot at it tomorrow.

Comment: For completeness, here is a definition of "no go", http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/no-go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look up the `ISelectionProvider` rather than the `ISelectionService`. That will provide you with a `setSelection()` method.

You can get the selction provider from the site:

```
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActivePart().getSite().getSelectionProvider();
```

or

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor().getSite().getSelectionProvider();
```

Note that some of those return values could be null so add the appropriate checks.

Comment: Thanks Nick, worked great, I also wanted to clear the selection of some of the widget that issued the event, so I ended upp with this: 
`if (event.widget instanceof Table) {
((Table)event.widget).deselectAll();
} else if (event.widget instanceof Tree){
((Tree)event.widget).deselectAll();
} 
ISelectionProvider selectionProvider = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActivePart().getSite().getSelectionProvider();
selectionProvider.setSelection(StructuredSelection.EMPTY);
`

Answer (score 0):

You can't clear the selection provided by the selection service directly.

The selection the service returns is provided by a 'selection provider' (`ISelectionProvider`) for the current part.

You can get the selection provider from an `IWorkbenchPart` with `IWorkbenchPart.getSite().getSelectionProvider()`.

`ISelectionProvider` has a `setSelection` method but it often does nothing or throws an exception so you may not be able to clear the selection.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449, though I accepted Nicks answer as the selection providers `setSelection(StructuredSelection.EMPTY)` method actually works as I wanted to: listeners of the selection service receives the empty selection.

Comment: You will find it is very unreliable, many parts ignore the `setSelection`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll keep it in mind. Works like a charm with my three parts application